# Git push origin head not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

So I was a windows 10 user and I work with a lot of branches. Everytime that I needed to do a push in a branch, I would use git push origin head.

2 days ago I decided to give ubuntu a try and I'm enjoying working with it. The only problem is git push origin head doesn't work anymore, everytime that I want to push to a branch, I have to use git push origin and that branch name.

Is there a reason for that? It's not the end of the world, but I really miss using head instead of typing down the branch name

Comment: Are you writing `head` in lower case or `HEAD` in upper case?

Comment: i was writing it in lowercase, that was the problem. torek's comment fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always write `HEAD` in all uppercase.  Git treats this particular name specially.  It *does not* treat lowercase `head` specially.

Using lowercase *sometimes* works on some machines.  In particular, it commonly works on Windows and MacOS ... *sometimes*.  But if you use `git worktree add` and work in an added work-tree, it stops working on Windows and MacOS too.

If you don't like holding the shift key down that long, consider using the `@` spelling for the magic name.

#### Why `head` (lowercase) works *sometimes* but not always

Git currently stores the HEAD information—the name of the current branch—in a file named `.git/HEAD`, except in added work-trees where it stores the (per-added-worktree) HEAD information in a file within a sub-folder of `.git`.

When you write `HEAD` in all capitals like this, Git knows to look for the `HEAD` information in the appropriate file—whether that's `.git/HEAD` or `.git/worktrees/.../HEAD` or whatever it might be.  So it goes straight to the correct information.

When you write `head` in lowercase, though, Git tries instead to use it as a tag name (`refs/tags/head`), or as a branch name (`refs/heads/head`), or as a remote-tracking name such as `refs/remotes/origin/head`.  This test is somewhat case-sensitive, because Git stores branch, tag, and remote-tracking names in two places:

- they may be in the plain-text file named `.git/packed-refs`, and/or
- they may be stored in an ordinary file within the file system, under `.git/refs/`, e.g., `.git/refs/tags/head` would hold the hash ID associated with the tag named `head`.

**The lookup in `.git/packed-refs` is done directly by Git itself and is case-sensitive.  The lookup in `.git/refs/` is done by the operating system.**  The OS's lookup may be case-insensitive, depending on the OS and file system in use.

Of course, you probably do not have a tag or branch named `head`.  Your remotes might have a symbolic reference named `HEAD`, but before Git finds those, Git *also* tries looking in the ordinary plain-text files in `.git` to see if any of *those* are named `head`.  This test is again done by the operating system.

If your OS and file system combination is case-*in*sensitive, so that a request to open and read the file named `head` opens and reads instead the obviously completely unrelated  file named `HEAD`, well, then, you get the effect of referring to this `.git/HEAD` file.  So if you're in the main work-tree, whose HEAD information is in `.git/HEAD`, the all-lowercase name `head` winds up using that.

This fails on Linux, where the normal file systems understand that the file `head` and the file `HEAD` are two different files, in the same way that "Polish shoe polish" is not redundant.  But it also fails in added work-trees on Windows and MacOS, because Git only looks for the per-worktree HEAD information when you spell the name `HEAD`.  If you use `head` (lowercase), Git has the OS read `.git/head`, which gets you the branch information for the *main* work-tree instead of that for your *current* work-tree.